# Materialized Views and Indexes

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

Is there any way to force PostgreSQL to use an index that I created on a materialized view table? I tried every combination possible of moving the column attributes around to make Postgres to use my index...

I have this table:

```
=> explain select * from flight3mv1;
                         QUERY PLAN                          
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on flight3mv1  (cost=0.00..3.50 rows=150 width=26)
(1 row)
```

When I create my index on the materialized view, nothing changed on my query plan.

```
=> create index flight3mv1index on flight3mv1(c_nation,s_nation);
=> analyze flight3mv1;
=> explain select * from flight3mv1 where c_nation='CHINA' and s_nation='CHINA';

                                      QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on flight3mv1  (cost=0.00..4.25 rows=6 width=26)
   Filter: (((c_nation)::text = 'CHINA'::text) AND ((s_nation)::text = 'CHINA'::text))
(2 rows)
```

Here is my flight3mv1 table:

```
=> \d flight3mv1
    Materialized view "public.flight3mv1"
  Column  |         Type          | Modifiers 
----------+-----------------------+-----------
 c_nation | character varying(15) | 
 s_nation | character varying(15) | 
 d_year   | integer               | 
 revenue  | bigint                | 
Indexes:
    "flight3mv1index" btree (c_nation, s_nation) CLUSTER
```

Comment: An index is not efficient for such small count of rows (150). So query planner does not used it.

Comment: Abelisto is right. For such a tiny table an index will never be used.

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried to reload it with 200,000 rows, but I didn't get any improvement in performance. I guess that was still not enough.

Comment: Do you have _problems_ with performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Step 1: Index the underlying table
CREATE INDEX flight3mv1_index ON flight3mv1 (c_nation, s_nation);

-- Step 2: Refresh the materialized view
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW flight3mv1;

-- Step 3: Query the materialized view
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM flight3mv1 WHERE c_nation = 'CHINA' AND s_nation = 'CHINA';
```